# Create a Google App Engine Project Programatically in Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to find a way to dynamically create a project on Google App Engine using Go following [this example](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/create).
However, the documentation isn't very clear (at least for me) in how to proceed to authenticate the user and the Go example goes as far as saying:

```
// TODO: Fill required fields.
```

I also had a look at the [Go Client Library Documentation](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client) which made things even more confusing to me.

Has anyone used this API before or have found a way to programatically create a project in App Engine?

Comment: Is the issue with authentication or with filling the required fields? If it is the second, that should be more or less independent from the client library, just follow the format specified on the rest API call documentation. Before trying it on the client library, I would recommend to try the request on the APIs Explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/cloudresourcemanager/v1beta1/cloudresourcemanager.projects.create

Comment: I've tested through API explorer before and it works fine. I just don't know how to implement this authentication on my app. That's the bit I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize the API by calling cloudresourcemanager.New(hc), you pass an http client, that in the case of this example is authenticated by using the default credentials from the system. These credentials come from the default service account of App Engine or Compute Engine (not sure about the second though), depending on the environment you are in. If you are outside of Google Cloud, you can follow the instructions on the example:

```
// 2. This sample uses Application Default Credentials for authentication.
//    If not already done, install the gcloud CLI from
//    https://cloud.google.com/sdk/ and run
//    'gcloud beta auth application-default login'
```

If you do this, the default credentials will be taken from the user you used to log in on the command gcloud beta auth application-default login. Another possibility would be changing the code to generate the credentials by calling JWTConfigFromJson[1](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/google#JWTConfigFromJSON), that would explicitly load your credentials from a json file. Here[2](https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/google/example_test.go#L58) you can see an example of how to initialize an http client using this method.

Comment: None of the above will work. I've set the application-default account before and still getting error: Error context googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden. The second method can't work because credentials are set at project level, since a project is exactly what I'm trying to create I can create credentials beforehand

Comment: I am able to run create on v1 of the API on APIs Explorer, but not v1beta1. The create method is marked as alpha on the new version. Maybe it is not generally available yet?

Comment: Yep. I'm now focusing on the V1 api. I got in touch with the Cloud Platform Support team and the v1 is actually the recommended method to do so. The problem now is that I can't get v1 to work outside of the API explorer due to some authentication issue. I've posted a new question for this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800765/create-google-cloud-project-with-cloud-resource-manager-api