# Create Google Cloud Project with Cloud Resource Manager API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create a new project in the Google Cloud Platform using the [Cloud Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create).
It all works fine when I use it through the API explorer however I don't quite understand how to use it as an http request outside of API Explorer.

I run the request like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name": "project example","projectId": "my-project-example-1234"}' https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects?fields=response&key={MY_APY_KEY}
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "The request does not have valid authentication credentials.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

The documentation says that this request [requires an OAuth scope](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create#authorization) and that's when things get confusing to me.
Reading the documentation I could not understand how one of the required OAuth scopes can be passed with the URL when making the http request to the rest API which I'm only assuming is what I'm missing.

Comment: Scopes are passed during OAuth authentication, not subsequent use of the credentials: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#oauth_scopes
and https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/authorizing.

Comment: I assume the curl requests are just for testing: what is your target language that you want to use? Are you planning on creating the projects on behalf of your end user or are you wanting to create the projects with your own account as the owner?

Comment: @BrettJ. You get the idea. I'm using Go and I'd create projects on behalf of my end user not the default account like all the examples I could find here.

Comment: Go isn't my strong suit, but posted an answer with a cross-link to a sample project that might get you far enough along.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than just tell you how to test with a working token, I'm going to try to more broadly answer what you're aiming to do.

At a pretty high level, you will need to:

1. [Enable the Resource Manager API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/overview) for your Cloud Console project.
2. [Create an OAuth client ID for Web applications](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient) in the Cloud Console. You will need to register your authorized redirect URI. This is where your app will get the OAuth response back from Google when the end user authorizes your app. Note the client ID, you will need that next.
3. Start the OAuth flow by assembling your URL:

   ```
   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
   response_type=code&
   client_id=<123456789example>.apps.googleusercontent.com&
   scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects&
   redirect_uri=http://<YOUR-APP-URL>/<YOUR-OAUTH-HANDLER>
   ```

   Replace in that URL the client ID and the redirect URI. I assume you'd have a button or link on your site where you would have the user click to start this flow.
4. Code your OAuth handler. Some more in-depth code for doing this in Go can be gleaned from [this Go Sample](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-go/blob/master/main.go), which was originally for G+ sign-in but much of the logic is going to be the same. You are going to get a `code` query parameter passed to your application, the value is a one-time authorization code that your application must exchange for your OAuth tokens that you use to make API calls on behalf of the user.
5. If appropriate for your app and situation, securely store your tokens for use later or for processing while your user is not active on your site (might be appropriate for batch processing).
6. Now that you have an access token, you can pass that to the Resource Manager API and create projects on behalf of the user. You might use the [Go client library](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/libraries) or you could call the HTTP endpoints directly in your code.

If you want more testing with curl, I'd follow the process that we wrote up [accessing the App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/accessing-the-api). Substitute Admin API URLs and names for Resource Manager and you've got the overall flow. The difference from what's above, is I used a `code` flow above because I assume you want server-side and possibly refresh tokens if you need to be able to make these API calls while the user is not active on your site.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63971562/how-to-create-project-in-google-console-cloud-platform-using-php-lib-programmati here is my question @BrettJ . please answer

Answer (score 0):

Like Alex says, you ask for scopes during OAuth authentication. One way to easily authenticate and obtain a Oauth access token is doing:

gcloud beta auth application-default login --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects

As you can see, you can specify the scopes you want to gcloud and it will take care of authentication for you.

Then, you should be able to create a project calling:

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud beta auth application-default print-access-token)" -X POST -d '{"name": "project example","projectId": "my-project-example-1234"}' https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects?fields=response

Here, you are passing the access token obtained when you made Oauth authentication. This should be taken care of by the client libraries for you when you get the application default credentials.

Comment: Thanks for that but I can't accept this answer. What's the point of using an API if I have to use gcloud tool with it? It just goes against the whole purpose of the api itself. Otherwise I could use gcloud altogether and would have no need for the api. I'm aware of the method you described here and that's exactly what I want to avoid. As I said in the question, it does work through the API explorer which uses exactly the same method as you described, the difference is that instead of gcloud it does redirect to a google login screen.

Comment: Well, you are using curl to test your request and see if it works from outside the APIs Explorer. To test with curl you need a valid access token (the request needs to be authenticated). I wouldn't see the point of manually doing Oauth authentication. Even Google uses this procedure on their examples: https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/curl#send_the_build_request

Comment: If you really want to do everything using curl exclusively, you would need to do 2 requests. One against Google Oauth 2.0 endpoints to authenticate and obtain a valid access token, and another one to call your API using the obtained token.Google discourages using this directly, and I am not sure how it would help you understand your request to Cloud Resource Manager API more. In any case, passing --log-http to gcloud tool is a good way to see the underlying request to the Oauth 2.0 endpoints if you are interested.